# Centering image and text within a div

Tags: image, html, vertical-alignment

In my asp.net mvc4 view I have some nested divs to show an image and under it a text like below:

```
<div id="Outer1" class="elementStatus">
    <div class="image"> <!-- THIS IS THE IMAGE -->
        <img id="MyImg1" src="@Url.Content("~/images/Image.gif")">
    </div>
    <div class="text"> <!-- THIS SHOWN THE TEXT UNDER IMAGE-->
        Statuts Text
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.elementStatus
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.image{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-top: 1px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 35px;    
}
.text{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    width: 35%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

I want that the image in the first div to be centered horizontally and vertically in the div where it is placed. The same for the second div, I want the text to be centered horizontally and vertically within its div. So how to do it?

**Please**, do not downvote!

Comment: Provide us fiddle please. (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: I don't see any attempt at centering in the code provided. What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @imjared I want to support IE 7,8,9,10 (if posible also IE6)

Comment: @showdev i have tried adding this to .image and .text:           text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;

Comment: To clarify, you want the two divs `div.image` and `div.text` to be stacked vertically (not floated) and each should be centered horizontally and vertically in `div#Outer1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend a background image:

```
.image {
    background-image: url('~/images/Image.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 35px 35px;
}
```

For the text:

```
.text {
    text-align: center;
}
```

For vertical text alignment:

```
.text {
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you recommend a background image?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question but it's easily solved using flexbox (assuming you're supporting newer browsers). Going to remove vendor prefixes for the sake of clarity but you'll want something like this:

```
#Outer1 {
    display: box;
    box-align: center;
    box-orient: vertical;
    box-pack: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VqwLH/

Since you have updated saying you need support for older browsers, I think you can use `display: table-cell` for the parent container:

```
#Outer1 {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VqwLH/1/

Comment: This is great, except for "I want to support IE 7,8,9,10 (if posible also IE6)".